# Getting b'' as an output when attempted to print data from a counting scale

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm trying to connect a counting scale to computer using RS232 cable to USB. I would like to validate the count by running a Python program. But I'm getting b'' as an output when I run the program instead of numbers.

```
ser=serial.Serial(port="COM4", baudrate=9600, timeout=5, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
#closes the port and opens it every time the program runs
if not ser.isOpen():
    ser.open()
print("COM3 is open", ser.isOpen())

#ser.isOpen()

while 1:
    #bytestoRead=ser.in_waiting()
    data=ser.read()
    time.sleep(2) #sleep after 2 seconds
    print(data)
```

Thanks.

Does anyone know why is that and how could that be fixed?

Comment: `b''` is an empty byte string. That means `ser.read()` didn't return anything.

Comment: Use `if len(data) > 0:` to tell if there's any data.